# Copying array elements within multidimensional arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I'm having some trouble with this in java. This method is supposed to take in two String arrays which are multidimensional. This method is supposed to return a a copy String array. Now these two arrays that are being sent to the copy method are going to have randomly generated lengths within the arrays. I am trying to see if array2 is smaller than array and if it is then array will be assigned the length of array2 and I want to copy elements from array into array2. If it is the opposite with array2 being bigger than array then I would like to copy the elements from array into array2 and then the REMAINING spots in array2 will get filled with an *. Now the issue is I keep getting runtime errors with out of bounds for the index. It is specifically the lines that I have indicated with double asterisks below(within for loops) that are giving me issues. What could I do to solve the issue.

```
    public static String[][][] copy(String[][][] array, String[][][] array2){
    if(array2.length < array.length){
        array = new String[array2.length][array2.length][array2.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < array2[i].length; j++){
                for(int k = 0; k < array2[i][j].length; k++){
                    **array2[i][j][k] = array[i][j][k];**
                }
            }
        }
        return array2; 
    }
    if(array2.length > array.length){

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
                for(int k = 0; k < array[i][j].length; k++){
                    **array2[i][j][k] = array[i][j][k];**
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i = array.length - 1; i < array2.length; i++){
            for(int j = array[i].length - 1; j < array2.length; j++){
                for(int k = array[i][j].length - 1; k < array2.length; k++){
                    array2[i][j][k] = "*";
                }
            }
        }
        return array2;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: could someone else provide any input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assume that each dimension of the array is of equal size.
But you cannot even assume that two sibling arrays are of equal size.
What I mean is, that `array = new String[array2.length][array2.length][array2.length];` is nonsense and at least in two ways.
You probably want to have `array2 = new String[array.length][][]`, because if you reassign `array` you will just copy `null`s around. And for the lengths of the other dimensions you have to do the same comparisons and resizings, especially if you did not reassign the `array2`. If you did, then you have to create the sub-level arrays afresh anyway.

Comment: That's a start, but by far not the fix of your code. Start a debugger and try understanding your code. And maybe read a book about Java and its arrays. ;-)

Comment: for the first if statement, only array elements up to the length of array2 should be copied so I'm not so sure if array2 = new String[array.length][][] would work.

Comment: Probably not, but if you copy from `array` to `array2`, `array2` is smaller than `array` and you should crop at `array2.length`, then it makes absolutely no sense to assign `array` or `array2` with a new value at all.

Comment: Ya I just tried both ways and I'm still getting runtime errors for that specific line.

Comment: As I told you, your code logic is **totally** screwed. You have to completely rethink or debug your logic. I just explained you your question, which was why you get AIOOBEs.